# How to specify the JDK compile level of a module in Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a pure Java module in an Android project. My project compiles by default using JDK 8, but I want my Java module to compile using JDK 7. How do I specify for my pure java module a compile level of 1.7? Keep in mind that I am not wanting to override the project level compile level of 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

```
//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

You can specify the source and target compatibility levels. This is needed often when compiling a mix of Android and Java modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways:

1-Add this block to your **app build.gradle**

```
android{
....
  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

2-Add this block with android studio:

- Go to **File>Project Structure**.
- In **Modules section**,select your **app** (or other modules) module.
- Change *Source compatibility* and *Target Compatibility* values to *1.8*.

**Update:**

Note: If you using kotlin as your Gradle language(kotlin dsl), you should do it this way:

```
android{
....
  compileOptions {
      setSourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
      setTargetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

1. In `gradle.properties` in your HOME_DIRECTORY set `org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory`
2. In your `gradle.build`

   ```
   compileJava.options.fork = true
   compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = /path_to_javac
   ```

Comment: Isn't this project wide though?

Answer (score 0):

Setting target/source compatibility levels of a java library module in Android Studio can be done adding this to the build.gradle of the java library module:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following into `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    } 
}
```

Comment: That is Android specific. I am building a mix of Java and Android modules. please read the question.

Comment: If you have any knowledge about that, you had only to add `compileOptions` out of `android` part.